# Prove that $V=W\oplus W^\perp$ when $W$ is a closed subspace of $V$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $(V,\left<\cdot ,\cdot \right>)$ a Hilbert space and $W\leq V$ a closed subspace. Prove that $$V=W\oplus W^\perp.$$

Can someone check my proof ?

Let $$W=\overline{Span\{w_i\}_{i\in \mathcal I}}.$$

Let $v\in V$. Since $v=Proj_W(v)+v-Proj_W(v)$, I would like to prove that $v-Proj_W(v)\in W^\perp$. I tried as follow : there is a sequence of $(w_n)\in Span\{w_i\}_{i\in \mathcal I}$ s.t. $w^n\to Proj_W(v)$ and $$w^n=\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha _i^n w_{k_i}$$ where $w_{k_i}\in \{w_i\}_{i\in I}$. Now, I'm not so sure what to do, because, there is no reason that $v-w^n\in W^\perp$ neither that $\lim_{n\to \infty }v-w^n\in W^\perp$ (since $W^\perp$ is not supposed closed).

Any idea ?

Comment: $W^\bot$ is closed for any set $W$. It is true even in more general setting of a normed space $V$.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you can do as in the finite dimensional case. The fact that $W+W^\perp$ is a direct sum is quite obvious. To prove that it's equal to $V$, let $v\in V$ and $\delta =\inf_{w\in W}\|v-w\|.$$

- There is $u\in W$ s.t. $$\|v-u\|=\delta .$$ Indeed, let $(u_n)$ a sequence of $W$ s.t. $\|v-u_n\|\to \delta $. One can prove that such a sequence is a Cauchy sequence, and thus it converges to some $v\in W$ (because $W$ is closed).
- Now, you have to show that $v-u\in Y^\perp$. For all $z\in W$ and all $t\in\mathbb R$, if $u+tz\in W$, then $$\delta ^2\leq \|v-u-tz\|^2=\|v-u\|^2+t^2\|z\|^2-2t\left<v-u,z\right>=:f(t).$$
  You have that $f$ has a minimum at $t=0$, and thus $f'(0)=0$, i.e. $\left<v-u,z\right>=0$ as wished.
- Since $v=u+v-u$, the claim follow.